# simul() can't find variables in expressions

Tags: r, object

I get the following error when executing the below code. It appears to be due to not assigning global parameters, however, this appears to create an issue,  when ncfn and ncfp are assigned to be global. Please can you assist

```
#Install libraries
library(MASS)
library(actuar)

#Set globals
set.seed(1)
sims<-10

#Set claim frequency
claim_freq_n<-5
claim_freq_p<-0.5

#Create function to simulate claim severity, set n globally as number of claims to generate, set m globally as parameters of severity distribution
claimsev<-function(n,m) { 
  rep(100,n) #use for testing
}

#Create function to generate two tables, first table has all projected losses, second table has number of losses by simulation.
SimX<-function(ncfn,ncfp,nyr)    { 
  #sims  = number of simulations

  #The expressions for ms and mf are dependent on the parameters being set at global level, so need << assignment and removal at end of these global values

  nodes <- list(year = nyr)
  mf <- expression(year=rnbinom(ncfn,ncfp))
  ms <- expression(year=claimsev(global_m))
  pf <- simul(nodes, mf, ms)

  #now clean up
  rm(list=grep("glob", ls(1), value=T), envir=globalenv())

  #check
  global_test<<-frequency(pf,classification=FALSE)
  print(fm<-mean(frequency(pf,classification=FALSE)))
  sf<-severity(pf, by = "year")   #see severity claims by year
  sn<-as.numeric(frequency(pf,classification=FALSE)) 

  return(list(sf$main,sn))
}

#Apply per claim and policy deductibles and limits
z<-SimX(claim_freq_n,claim_freq_p,sims)
```

Error in rnbinom(ncfn, ncfp, n = 10) : object 'ncfn' not found

Comment: @JohnColeman it's `pf <- simul(nodes, mf, ms)`. Expression is being evaluated but it doesn't find the objects. Perhaps wrapping everything in `eval()` would help?

Answer (score 1):

In the `simul` function, there comes a point where they evaluate your expressions that you pass in with

```
eval(Call)
```

Because they don't explicitly specify an environment where to evaluate that expression, it is evaluated in the environment of the `simul` function which does not contain the variable `ncfn`. That variable is defined in the environment of your `SimX` function. Note that variables are not searched in environment where functions are called from, rather R is lexically scoped so variables are looked up in environments where functions are defined. Thus `simul` can't find the values of  `ncfn`.

The solution is to evaluate those parameters before you call `simul`. Here's one way

```
mf <- as.expression(c(year=bquote(rbindom(.(ncfn), .(ncfp)))))
# or
mf <- as.expression(c(year=substitute(rbindom(n, p), list(n=ncfn, p=ncfp))))
```

This will evaulate to

```
mf
# expression(year = rbindom(5, 0.5))
```

which is then safe to pass into `simul()` so there are no variables that need to be looked up.

You would do the same for `ms` as well. Wasn't able to test it because `global_m` isn't defined in your example